# How can I do an OR operation on the values of a solr field?

Tags: 6, search

Say I have a facet on countries, I'd like to be able to click on more than one country (say US and UK) and get results tagged "US" OR "UK".

Currently If I click on "UK" on the facet block, the other terms disappear if this was a "single solr field".

And if it was a multi-valued solr field, the other terms don't disappear but an AND operation is done.

How can I change the default behavior to allow OR operation on both "single" and "multi-valued" solr fields?

I'm using the Apache Solr Search Integration module version 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure if this is in 1.6 but if you configure the country facet block you'll get the option to use AND or OR inside the facet.

Comment: This isn't in v1.6, only in 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this documentation page

http://drupal.org/node/1159424

I have not tried it but just came across it.